# Load a pretrained model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to a pretrained model with several methods but i get always errors.  The model is saved in a hub file with five files in it, one is called `saved_model.pb` and the second is called `tfhub_module.pb`. There is an additional folder called `variables` and containing two files : `variables.data.0xxx` and `variables.index`.  i precise that i do not know the model's architecture. How can i call and use this pretrained model in tensorflow (TF2)

I tried this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model_path = '/path/to/your/model/directory'
try:
    model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path, tags=['serving_default'])
except KeyError:
    print("Error: 'serving_default' tag not found. Trying other tags...")
```

But i do not know what to do next

Comment: I would recommend creating your own model, then save it, then load it. All of these steps are explained in docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

Comment: It would be helpful to know the error messages/stack trace instead of "got errors". And, if possible, a link to the model hub files.

Comment: I found [this article about hub models](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/model_formats#tf1_hub_format), which stated that `tfhub_module.pb` files are part of TF1 hub models. Depending on your pre-trained model, it would be better to try and get a TF2 compatible pre-trained model.